# NSNotificationCenter is not calling in swift2.2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

```
let imageDataDict:[String: UIImage] = ["SelectedImages": image!]
                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("PosterImage", object: self, userInfo: imageDataDict)

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(frameViewController.takeImages(_:)), name:"PosterImage", object: nil)


func takeImages(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let singleImage = notification.userInfo?["SelectedImages"] as? UIImage {
        // do something with your image
        self.f_singlImage = singleImage
    }
}
```

I am working on NSNotificationCenter but  it's not working properly in swift 2.2 . i tried alot no hope the resolve this  .I am new to swift and any one explain this

Comment: @kirit Modi : takeImages( ) method not fiiring .....

Comment: if you are calling postNotificationName: method before the Add observer then its not call.

Comment: @KiritModi : i did for different places